# How to solve the following fourth order partial differential equation including Laplacian

Tags: differential-equations

I wish to solve the following fourth order partial differential equation including Laplacian
[image]

with the boundary conditions
[image]

with the initial conditions

[image]

```
\[Nu] = 0.34;
\[Beta] = 0.4;
solution = NDSolve[{
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "0", ",", "2"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r, \[Theta], t] + 
 Laplacian[
  Laplacian[w[r, \[Theta], t], {r, \[Theta]}, 
   "Polar"], {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"] == 16, 
w[\[Beta], \[Theta], t] == 0,

\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Beta], \[Theta], t] == 0,

\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[1, \[Theta], t] + \[Nu]/1*
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[1, \[Theta], t] + \[Nu]/1^2*
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[1, \[Theta], t] == 0,
 ((D[Laplacian[w[r, \[Theta], t], {r, \[Theta]}, "Polar"], r] + (
     1 - \[Nu])/r^2*D[
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(w\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[r, \[Theta], t] - w[r, \[Theta], t]/
       r, {\[Theta], 2}]) /. r -> 1) == 0,
w[r, \[Theta], 0] == 0}, 
w[r, \[Theta], t], {r, 0.4, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

I tried to solve it with NDSolve, but failed

Comment: Define "failed." What _exactly_ happened?

Comment: @rcollyer NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable. >>

Comment: @bbgodfrey   I guess NDSolve cannot Solve the partial differential equations with the implicit boundaty condition

Comment: Because the PDE is second-order in time, a second boundary condition in time probably is needed.

Comment: You might need a periodicity boundary condition in $\theta$ as well — Mathematica doesn't know by default that $w(r,0,t) = w (r, 2\pi, t)$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Seifert  I have already attempted，the same notification, NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Probably, higher order bc's in θ also are needed, because the PDE is fourth-order in θ.

Comment: @1112131424  As I noted in an earlier comment, a second boundary condition in time is needed.  When provided, the `NDSolve::ivone` error goes away but only to be replaced by a `NDSolve::bcnorm: ` error condition, which may be more difficult to address.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  NDSolve::pdnbc: Mixed periodic and Dirichlet/Neumann boundary conditions are not allowed. >>

Comment: @1112131424  If all else fails, you can discretize the equation in the spatial variables yourself, creating a large set of coupled second-order ODEs, which `NDSolve` should be able to solve without difficulty.  See [The Numerical Method of Lines for examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Solving this problem is probably going to get you in to the deep weeds of `Method` specifications in `NDSolve`.  When Mathematica encounters the code as originally stated, it defaults to a finite element method.  The problem is that Mathematica's finite element methods can't handle equations with higher than second-order derivatives in the spatial variables, hence the error message:

> NDSolve::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two. >>

We can force Mathematica to use finite-difference methods instead of finite-element methods by specifying

```
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> "TensorProductGrid"}}
```

but if you do this, you get the other error message

> NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable. >>

As has been pointed out in the comments, your problem as stated doesn't have the correct number of boundary conditions;  `NDSolve` will throw the above error either when it's using finite-difference methods and you have either too many boundary conditions or too few.  (See the page `ref/message/NDSolve/ivone` in the documentation.)  I *believe* this is why the solver is defaulting to finite-element methods;  you can leave some boundary conditions unspecified in these methods, and Mathematica will effectively fill them for you.  (I'm not 100% clear on how it does this;  I believe they're effectively Neumann boundary conditions for which the normal derivatives vanish, but I welcome correction.)

For your case, you would probably need conditions on the zeroth through third derivatives with respect to $r$ and $\theta$ at the boundaries $r = \beta$ and 1 and $\theta = 0$ and $2 \pi$.  (The "zeroth" derivative is, of course, the function itself.)  You would also need conditions on the zeroth and first derivatives with respect to $t$ at $t = 0$.  If boundary conditions are specified on a rectangular region, then I believe that the above `Method` specification is no longer necessary;  but there may be other wrinkles that you might yet run into once these problems are fixed....

Comment: I know what your mean,thank you for your help.I will change my program tomorrow.